# Beginners help in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a simple directive. It should output 'kk' string. But it does not. Could you please take a look and point the mistake?

http://jsbin.com/qunuqereneya/1/edit

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <menu></menu>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

var mainModule = angular.module('MainModule', []);

```
mainModule.directive('Menu', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'kk'
    };
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a couple issues in your code:

1. `ng-app` needs to be declared on the page.  This defines the context of your app:
2. Capitalization matters, change `Menu` to `menu`.

HTML:

```
 <html ng-app="MainModule">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```

JS:

```
var mainModule = angular.module('MainModule', []);

mainModule.directive('menu', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'kk'
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that this directive works only with name 'menu', but it does not with name 'Menu' (changed both in HTML and JS). Could you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define your app. 
put ng-app="MainModule" on your body element, then it should work.

```
<body ng-app="MainModule">
```